# ¿Cómo Abrir carpetas C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo un botón en le formulario el cual deseo abrir cualquier carpeta del computador

tengo estos comando en el evento click del botón

```
string Ruta = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", Ruta);
```

Necesito abrir una carpeta especifica que esta en mi escritorio

Comment: explorer.exe %UserProfile%\desktop  <--- parece que con esa instrucción lo puedes hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta el código que tienes:

```
string Ruta = "NombreDeLaCarpeta";//Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
//suponiendo que ruta es la carpeta tuya del escritorio.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe","%UserProfile%\desktop\" + Ruta);
```

Answer (score -1):

Estás accediendo a las [carpetas especiales de Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8), pero deberías apuntar a la carpeta especial de "Mis Documentos" que está en `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`. Luego le concatenas el nombre de la carpeta a abrir.

```
string Ruta = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
Ruta += "\\CarpetaParaAbrir"
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", Ruta);
```